# Grep and filter out values from a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a requirement to grep values from a xml file in shell
sample file below: test.xml

```
<wtc-import>
      <name>WTCImportedService-288-rap04</name>
      <resource-name>CAC040F</resource-name>
      <local-access-point>lap01</local-access-point>
      <remote-access-point-list>rap04</remote-access-point-list>
      <remote-name>CAC040F</remote-name>
    </wtc-import>
    <wtc-import>
      <name>WTCImportedService-289-rap04</name>
      <resource-name>CAD040F</resource-name>
      <local-access-point>lap01</local-access-point>
      <remote-access-point-list>rap04</remote-access-point-list>
      <remote-name>CAD040F</remote-name>
    </wtc-import>
   <wtc-import>
      <name>WTCImportedService-290-rap04</name>
      <resource-name>CAE040F</resource-name>
      <local-access-point>lap01</local-access-point>
      <remote-access-point-list>rap04</remote-access-point-list>
      <remote-name>CAE040F</remote-name>
    </wtc-import>
    <wtc-import>
  <name>WTCImportedService-289-rap04</name>
  <resource-name>CAD040F</resource-name>
  <local-access-point>lap01</local-access-point>
  <remote-access-point-list>rap04</remote-access-point-list>
  <remote-name>CAD040F</remote-name>
</wtc-import>
```

Have to grep all values associated with  in he file and at last if any duplicate resource name present remove the duplicated from the output file

Execpted output:

```
CAC040F
CAD040F
CAE040F
```

the resource CAD040F is a duplicate so in the expected output its just appeared once

Tried:

```
grep 'resource-name' test.xml | awk -F">" '{print $2}' | awk -F"<" '{print $1}'
```

and this is working good..how about filtering duplicates after that?

Comment: Have you tried adding `| sort -u` after?

Comment: Please don't edit your answer into your question. Instead, post it as an answer so others can vote on it. I have reverted your question edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single awk command

```
awk -F"[<>]" '/resource-name/ && !seen[$3]++ { print $3 } ' test.xml
```

with your sample xml file

```
$ awk -F"[<>]" '/resource-name/ && !seen[$3]++ { print $3 } ' test.xml
CAC040F
CAD040F
CAE040F

$
```

Answer (score 1):

Just speed optimization compare to @stack0114106 that already the job

```
awk -F '[<>]' '$2 == "resource-name" && ! ( $3 in List) { print $3; List[$3] } ' test.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already getting the output and just looking to remove duplicates , the easiest way to do that is piping the output to sort and then to uniq so your command will look like this

```
grep 'resource-name' test.xml | awk -F">" '{print $2}' | awk -F"<" '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: `sort -u` is equivalent to `sort | uniq` and has the advantage of not creating another subprocess.

Comment: if you use a awk in a pipe, try to avoid other text modifycation/catcher if possible (sometime a prevoious grep is interesting on huge file for memory and speed). Ex: `grep 'resource-name' test.xml | awk -F">" '{print $2}'`  => `awk -F">" '/resource-name/{print $2}' test.xml`

Answer (score 0):

If bash regex is your option, please try the following:

```
declare -A name
regex="<remote-name>([^<]+)</remote-name>"

while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
        name["${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"]=1
    fi
done < "test.xml"

for i in "${!name[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```